# How to preserve expression and turn into character in R?

Tags: r

If I have a vector like:

```
x <- c(1/5, 3 + 1, "HelloWorld", "3.14")
```

And I apply `as.character` to `x`, it returns:

```
> as.character(x)
[1] "0.2"        "4"          "HelloWorld" "3.14"
```

But I'm trying to find a way to preserve the expression as a character. So, when I call `x` it would return:

```
> x
[1] "1/5"        "3 + 1"      "HelloWorld" "3.14"
```

How could I do this?"

Comment: The second you assign it like `x <- c(...` the original expression is gone. Only the evaluated result is stored.

Comment: Ah ok, so essentially what Im trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this one could help

```
> as.character(quote(c(1 / 5, 3 + 1, "HelloWorld", "3.14")))[-1]
[1] "1/5"        "3 + 1"      "HelloWorld" "3.14"
```

Comment: As per @thelatemail comment... it seems that what im trying to do is impossible. Essentially I was trying to do `as.character(quote(x))[-1]`... but as Ive learned that once we assign the expression to `x`, the original expression is gone

Comment: @Electrino Yes, one you finish `x <- c(....)`, the expression is already parsed and evaluated.